# how to debug Azure node.js web service running locally

Tags: node.js, azure, iisnode

How can this noble goal be achieved? I already changed my web.config to contain this:

```
<iisnode 
  debuggingEnabled="true"
  loggingEnabled="true"
  devErrorsEnabled="true"
/>
```

And when I hit this URL on my emulated web role http://localhost/server.js/debug/ I get this:

The iisnode module is unable to deploy supporting files necessary to initialize the debugger. Please check that the identity of the IIS application pool running the node.js application has read and write access permissions to the directory on the server where the node.js application is located.

Answer (score 2):

node-inspector debugging support requires 3rd party modules not included in the "Windows Azure SDK for Node.JS" WebPI.

You need to uninstall IISNode (Control Panel / uninstall program) and 
install "full" IIS-Node edition from 
https://github.com/downloads/tjanczuk/iisnode/iisnode-full-iis7-v0.1.11-x86.msi 
or 
https://github.com/downloads/tjanczuk/iisnode/iisnode-full-iis7-v0.1.11-x64.msi

then repeat the configuration steps you're doing.

Comment: By default when you install the msi above the debugger will be enabled locally in the emulator. To enable in the cloud you should modify web.cloud.config and not web.config. Just be aware if you enable in the cloud that it is highly insecure as all the data is passed in plain text. You should not use as is for debugging a production application.

Comment: agh. you should ship this kind of debugger support with webmatrix 2 all hooked up and ready to go. If MS is anything it's tooling support. :P